# What timezone does the `at` command use?

Tags: date, scheduling, at

I've searched in the man pages for the `at` command there are no mentions of timezone or tz. There is [this](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/at):

> The exact definition of the time specification can be found in  `/usr/share/doc/at-3.1.10/timespec`.

Within that file I see this:

```
timezone_name   : UTC
                ;
```

I'm guessing that means this command uses UTC as the default timezone. But perhaps there is something I am missing and it will make use of the server's default timezone.

Comment: easy to test with `at 00:00 'date > ~/at-time-test'`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also states in `/usr/share/doc/at/timespec` that

```
time        : time_base
            | time_base timezone_name
            ;
```

which I take to mean that `at` uses **local time** or UTC
depending on whether "UTC" is specified. 
My recollection is that this is the case,
although it is some time since I have used `at` or `batch`.

Comment: **Local time** being whatever you've chosen for your session using the TZ environment variable, or if you haven't, then the system default timezone.

Comment: Setting `TZ` doesn't seem to work.  `TZ=MDT at 0800` still schedules according to the system's timezone `Etc/UTC` from `/etc/timezone`.  This is `at 3.2.5` on Ubuntu 22.10.